# Accessing AddressBook without picker or UI

Tags: iphone

I have read somewhere that Aurora Feint managed to access the Address Book without using the picker. Is it possible to iterate through all records? Aurora Feint is available on AppStore, so I assume they are using SDK with no private frameworks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to operate on the iPhone addressbook using pretty standard AB* functions. This includes iterating over the existing contacts in the addressbook and each of the attributes of a contact. Not the easiest API to use but there are samples available.

Comment: I haven't found a way to get the default Address Book instance. I can create a new one, but how do I access the one that's already there? The Address Book Picker does it, but I'm too tired to disassemble :)

Any ideas?

Comment: The documentation on how to create an addressbook explains all. It's really straightforward and a one liner in the API documentation.